# Ошибка кодировки БД

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Есть БД. При экспорте или просмотре на PHPMyAdmin кириллицу показывает некорректно. Но при подключении этого файла на сайт данные отображаться корректно. Можно ли исправить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так настройте правильно кодировку в PHPMyAdmin-то.

Comment: не подскажите как?

Comment: Да понятия не имею - ибо не пользую это поделие. Просто вижу, что UTF-8 выводится как CP1251.